# UIpickerView populating multiple uitextFields in the same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

Hi I am developing an iphone app where I have populated a uipickerview and it works great with one uitextfield. But I have 4 uitextfield I need to populate and I am using the same uipickerview for each UItextfield. I have no idea how to implement this thing.

Pickerviewcontroller.m

```
 arrChooseServices=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+ve",@"A-ve",@"B+ve",@"B-ve",@"AB+ve",@"AB-ve",@"O+ve",@"O-ve", nil];

// Create UITextfield

 bloodGroup=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 200, 120, 20)];
bloodGroup.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

[bloodGroup setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
bloodGroup.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
bloodGroup.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
bloodGroup.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
bloodGroup.delegate=self;

bloodGroup.inputView=self.chooseServicePicker;
bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView=self.accessoryView;
[self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];


-(UIPickerView *)chooseServicePicker
{
  if(chooseServicePicker==nil)
  {
    chooseServicePicker=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    chooseServicePicker.delegate=self;
    chooseServicePicker.dataSource=self;
    chooseServicePicker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
 }
  return chooseServicePicker;
}

-(UIToolbar *)accessoryView
{

 if ( accessoryView == nil )
{
  accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
 UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(onVehicleSelection)];

 UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
accessoryView.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton,cancelButton, nil];

}
return accessoryView;
```

}

```
- (void)onVehicleSelection 
{

   NSInteger row = [self.chooseServicePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
  bloodGroup.text=[arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row];
  [bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
  return [arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

return ( arrChooseServices == nil ) ? 0 : [arrChooseServices count];

}

-(void)cancel
{

bloodGroup.text=@"";

[bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];

}
```

This is my code. Now i want to display another array values in another textfield using same UIPickerview

```
gender=[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjectis:@"MALE",@"Female",nil];
```

the above array values i want to add in Uipickerview. how to write the code. please give me any idea. I am new to the programming. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to show picker of same elements for all your text fields ..

Comment: no sir , i want to display different array values in different uitextfields using sampe pickerview

Comment: I have submitted my code first use it as a sample and check it worked for me. if you have any queries in the code feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check which text going to `becomeFirstResponder`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

And Based on this Condition

`[textField isFirstResponder]`

You can perform check what you need to display.

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if(textField1 isFirstResponder] 
         return [arrChooseServices objectAtIndex:row];

    else if(textField2 isFirstResponder] return [otherArray count]; 
    // write for every textfield other 
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
 {
    if(textField1 isFirstResponder] return 1;

    else if(textField2 isFirstResponder] return 3;
    //In this way you can do what you need to show in picker view.
    return 1;
  }



   //Same condition you can use in every delegate and datasource method.
```

Comment: hi sir,thanks for sending your answer.But my requirement is i have 3 textfields.and i have 3arrays values.I want to display 3array values are displaying corresponding textfield using same pickerview.

Comment: In my answer I given. When you firtTextField isFirstResponder then show corresponding array data. Do same comparision in ` -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` here. And load correspnding data.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
 {
UIPickerView *myPickerView;
int selectedTextfieldValue;
NSArray *namesArray , *genderArray, *ageArray;

 }
 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
    namesArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];
    genderArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"M",@"F", nil];
   ageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"26",@"25", nil];
  int yaxis =50;
  selectedTextfieldValue=0;
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
 {
  UITextField*  bloodGroup=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, yaxis, 120,20)];

 bloodGroup.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

 bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

 bloodGroup.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];
 // bloodGroup.tag=(int)i;// first tag will be ZERO but by default view tag is ZERO so
  bloodGroup.tag=(int)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"20%d",i] intValue];

  bloodGroup.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

  bloodGroup.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

  bloodGroup.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

  bloodGroup.delegate=self;

  [self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];
    yaxis=yaxis +30;
  }

  }
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
 NSLog(@"%d",textField.tag);
 selectedTextfieldValue=(int)textField.tag;
 // call picker here according to textfield tag you can set text to textfiled
 [self popoverWithInformation];
 }

 -(void)popoverWithInformation
 {
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];



[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
CGRect pickerRect = myPickerView.bounds;
myPickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);

UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[popoverView addSubview:myPickerView];

[popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[self.view addSubview:popoverView];
 }
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


 }

 // tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
 -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
int count = 0;

switch (selectedTextfieldValue) {
    case 200:
        count =namesArray.count;
        break;
      case 201:
        count =genderArray.count;
        break;
      case 202:
        count =ageArray.count;
        break;  
    default:
        break;
}

return count;
 }

 // tell the picker how many components it will have
 -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
 }

 // tell the picker the title for a given component
 -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *title;

switch (selectedTextfieldValue) {
     case 200:
        title =namesArray[row];
        break;
      case 201:
        title =genderArray[row];
        break;
      case 202:
        title =ageArray[row];
        break;  
    default:
        break;
}


return title;
 }

 // tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
 -(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
int sectionWidth = 300;

return sectionWidth;
 }

 -(void)pickerDone:(id)sender
 {


 }
 -(void)pickerCancel:(id)sender
 {


 }
```

Comment: Thanks brother.very nice answer.If i want to display another array values like male=[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Male"@"Female",nil]; in another textfield using same pickerview. how can i make the code using your code?

Comment: Hi sir,thanks for responding.i check your code.if i run i got error message like "spring board failed to launch application with error-3"

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I guess you need multi-column UIPickerView.

You need to define number of columns in this UIPickerViewDatasource method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

then in this method:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

you need to return number of rows for each component.

Example::

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
  return 3; // for four columns
}

   - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  if(component == 0)
  {
    return _array1.count; // 10 rows in 1st column
  }
  else  if(component == 1)
  {
    return _array2.count; // 15 rows in 1st column
  }
  else  if(component == 2)
  {
    return _array3.count; // 15 rows in 1st column
  }
}
```

Use this delegate method to fill your textfields, according to the row selected in `UIPickerView`

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   if(component == 0)
   {
       self.textfield1.text = [_array1 objectAtIndex:row];
   }
    else if(component == 1)
    {
        self.textfield2.text = [_array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(component == 2)
    {
        self.textfield3.text = [_array3 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Comment: no sir , i want to display different array values in different uitextfields using sampe pickerview

Comment: Here you will use the same picker view but with four columns and each column will have different array. And when you select each column the four different textfields will get populated. Is it not what you want?

Comment: hi sir,thanks for sending your answer.But my requirement is i have 3 textfields.and i have 3arrays values.I want to display 3array values are displaying corresponding textfield using same pickerview.

Comment: This is what you can achieve using the methods I have posted in my answer. For more clarification see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   textField.inputView = pickerView;
   //Set the Tag of Uipickerview
   pickerView.tag = textField.tag; // you could workaround with tag in delegate methods accordingly
   [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
   return YES;
}
```